# Set the action button graphic to a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I know the action button graphic is for a `UIBarButtonItem` but is it possible to set that image to a `UIButton`? I already have the action set up, it's just the graphic now.

Just to specify i want to set this image [image] to a `UIButton` programmatically.

Comment: I'm not working with a UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this, like there is for `UIBarButtonItem`. You'll need to create the icon yourself (in Sketch/Photoshop/whatever), and use that instead. Alternatively, there are plenty of vector icon sets available from various sources that will include this icon (a quick google will find one).